# php weird file_exists bug

Tags: php, file-exists

Has anyone got any idea to why doesn't the following work ?

```
$file = 'images/thumbs/1%20-%20Copy.jpg';
if(!file_exists($file)){
 die('NOT THERE');  
}

echo 'Yes its there.';
```

The problem is with the spaces. I have checked the file exists,dbl checked n triple checked im going nuts. :(

Help

Comment: btw I have double checked the case sensitivity aswell

Comment: This is a relative path, what means, that it is resolved against the current working directory (`getcwd()`). Did you checked the absolute path also (`realpath()`)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`file_exists` works on the file system and not via HTTP. So `%20` will not be recognized as space but literally as `%20`; use spaces instead:

```
$file = 'images/thumbs/1 - Copy.jpg';
```

Comment: ... and for the sake of completeness: the URL for a file with actual `%20` on its name should be `images%2Fthumbs%2F1%2520-%2520Copy.jpg` ;-)

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario: It would rather be `images/thumbs/1%2520-%2520Copy.jpg`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$file = rawurldecode('images/thumbs/1%20-%20Copy.jpg');
```

Answer (score 1):

try these two

```
$file = 'images/thumbs/1\ -\ Copy.jpg';
$file = 'images/thumbs/1 - Copy.jpg';
```